# append/extend list in loop

Tags: python

I would like to extend a list while looping over it:

```
for idx in xrange(len(a_list)):
    item = a_list[idx]
    a_list.extend(fun(item))
```

(fun is a function that returns a list.)

Question:
Is this already the best way to do it, or is something nicer and more compact possible?

Remarks:

```
from matplotlib.cbook import flatten
a_list.extend(flatten(fun(item) for item in a_list))
```

should work but I do not want my code to depend on matplotlib.

```
for item in a_list:
    a_list.extend(fun(item))
```

would be nice enough for my taste but seems to cause an infinite loop.

Context:
I have have a large number of nodes (in a dict) and some of them are special because they are on the boundary.
'a_list' contains the keys of these special/boundary nodes. Sometimes nodes are added and then every new node that is on the boundary needs to be added to 'a_list'. The new boundary nodes can be determined by the old boundary nodes (expresses here by 'fun') and every boundary node can add several new nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried list comprehensions? This would work by creating a separate list in memory, then assigning it to your original list once the comprehension is complete. Basically its the same as your second example, but instead of importing a flattening function, it flattens it through stacked list comprehensions. [edit Matthias: changed + to +=]

```
a_list += [x for lst in [fun(item) for item in a_list] for x in lst]
```

---

EDIT: To explain what going on.

So the first thing that will happen is this part in the middle of the above code:

```
[fun(item) for item in a_list]
```

This will apply `fun` to every `item` in `a_list` and add it to a new list. Problem is, because `fun(item)` returns a list, now we have a list of lists. So we run a second (stacked) list comprehension to loop through all the lists in our new list that we just created in the original comprehension:

```
for lst in [fun(item) for item in a_list]
```

This will allow us to loop through all the lists in order. So then:

```
[x for lst in [fun(item) for item in a_list] for x in lst]
```

This means take every `x` (that is, every item) in every `lst` (all the lists we created in our original comprehension) and add it to a new list.

Hope this is clearer. If not, I'm always willing to elaborate further.

Comment: I tried it and it works :-) even so I do now understand how *confused*

Comment: I'll edit it to make it more understandable. Btw, do you want to ADD the result of `fun(list)` to the original? Or you want to create a new list with `fun(item)` replacing each item in the list?

Comment: Every element in the original list makes several new element necessary to be added.
The resulting list should contain the original and the new elements. fun(item) takes an integer (which is actually an index) that decides which new elements are added.

Answer (score 2):

Using [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), it can be written as:

```
import itertools
a_list += itertools.chain(* itertools.imap(fun, a_list))
```

or, if you're aiming for code golf:

```
a_list += sum(map(fun, a_list), [])
```

Alternatively, just write it out:

```
new_elements = map(fun, a_list) # itertools.imap in Python 2.x
for ne in new_elements:
  a_list.extend(ne)
```

Comment: Note that this has quadratic behaviour as causes lots of needless list allocations and concatenations. Also, some (including me) have reservations on using `sum` for non-numeric stuff. `itertools.chain` /and also `itertools.imap` in 2.x) could be far more efficient.

Comment: @delnan Updated with an alternative, and your suggested version with itertools.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to extend the list, but loop only over the original list, you can loop over a copy instead of the original:

```
for item in a_list[:]:
     a_list.extend(fun(item))
```

Comment: I wanted to write exactly this for my this-does-not-work example; sorry, I corrected it now. Please try to run these two lines eg. for a_list = [1,2,3]; def fun(v): return [1+v,2] (and keep your finger over Ctrl+c)

Comment: @Matthias 009: well, obviously it is a infinite loop when the list constantly grows ... what are you trying to do?

Comment: The thing is I do not want the list to constantly grow, I want the behaviour of the first code example (the one with xrange and len)

Comment: @Matthias 009: why would you extend the list then ... simply make a new one.

Comment: making a new list would be ok, sure, but in what way would it be an advantage? (Note also that the start of the new list must be identical to the old list, because other parts of my program rely on that)

Answer (score 0):

Using generator

```py
original_list = [1, 2]
original_list.extend((x for x in original_list[:]))

# [1, 2, 1, 2]
```